# How to access values in node object?

Tags: 8, hooks

Hi i am unable to access values from a node object inside a **preprocess_views_view** . Below is a screenshot of my object and i want to access the value highlighted. How can i do that?
[image]

Comment: Yeah...infact i've created a custom view for my search result listing..I need to override a url in the view. That's why i need to access these elements so i can override the url.

Answer (score 3):

There are several options:

You can use the getter method for the node id (available for all entities):

```
$node->id()
```

You can use *magic methods* to access any field of any content entity:

```
$node->nid->value
```

The above code will actually trigger the below:

```
$node->get('nid')->get(0)->get('value')->getValue()
```

Comment: $node->id() works in hook_node_presave($node) and $node->nid->value doesn't, thanks.

Comment: Some field may be emtpy. You have to  `if (!$entity->get('field_name')->isEmpty()) ` to prevent errors

Answer (score 1):

To get the node id you can use `$node->id()`. Any object extending ContentEntityBase has this method.

You can look at the Node class to see what public getter methods are available (also, ContentEntityBase and Entity).

Note that protected values cannot be overwritten without a setter method - so you'll need to create a new variable from your preprocess hook to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging a content entity object is not very useful. Instead, debug its array representation (`$node->toArray()`), you can access that data then like this:

`$node->get('field')->property`. For example `$node->get('nid')->value`.

For base fields like the ID, there are usually also methods, in this case `$node->id()` as mentioned by others.

See [Entity API Cheat Sheet](https://wizzlern.nl/drupal/drupal-8-entity-cheat-sheet) for more information.