# Accessing menu protected data

Tags: 9

How can the protected data of a menu object, pictured below, be accessed ?

[image]

using `$menu->id()` works and returns the menu ID. But neighter `$menu->values` nor `$menu->get('values')` work.

Comment: To get all values use `->toArray()`. See the same question for nodes https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/233098/how-to-access-values-in-node-object

Answer (score 0):

It's a content entity so you access fields using magic methods, e.g.

```
$x = $menu->field_foo->value;
```

Comment: I tried `$menu->values->value` but that returned null. `$menu->values` is actually an array in the menu object. And I though magic methods are called using `$menu->get('values')` ?

Comment: `$values` actually holds the values for the entity properties (not class properties, possibly a bit confusing). When you use `$entity->foo`, you're requesting `$values['foo']`, via the magic method (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3A__get/8.2.x). You don't need to try to access `$values` directly itself, indeed you can't as there's no public method available, but you can use the magic get to request anything inside it. Hopefully that clears it up but if not, just edit the post and mention what you're...

Comment: ...trying to get at, and it should be easy enough to point you in the right direction